# WPF Grid child control ordering

Tags: wpf, xaml

How are child controls made to **appear in order** within a xaml `Grid`?

For e.g., using the following:

```
<Grid>
    <igRibbon:XamRibbon...>
    <igWindows:XamTabControl...>
    <igWindows:XamTabControl...>
</Grid>
```

I would like the

- ribbon to appear at the **top** of the window
- followed by the 2 XamTabControls **in order**

But, my XamTabControl seems to stretch **occupying the whole window** hiding the XamRibbon.

---

## Tried the following:

I'm sure this is not very tricky or difficult, but I couldn't find a proper control/property that needs to be set. I tried setting `Grid.Row="1"` (for the first XamTabControl), but that seemed to make no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1

By default controls will stretch to fit the size of the grid cell.  To fix this you can either define more than one grid row / column through something like ...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height=""/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=""/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Then you can explicitly set which column and row you want each control in via the Grid.Row and Grid.Column attached properties.  You can specify a height / width of the column / row, or leave that part out and they will default to being uniform.

If the `Height` of the first row is set to the value `Auto`, it distributes height evenly based on the size of the content that is within that row.

### Solution 2

Or change the vertical and horizontal alignment of each control inside from stretch to some other value.

### Solution 3

A third solution could be change the `<Grid>` to a `<UniformGrid>`

Comment: Thank you! WPF is like an ocean. Need to wade through so much to find a small thing...

Answer (score 1):

Add row definitions to your grid.

Ex:

```
    <Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Then setting Grid.Row should respond with ordering of the children.